# Callback when using test numbers

Tags: sinch

When placing a call to one of the test numbers (e.g. 460000000001), I receive a callback (event "ice") with the following data:

```
"to": {
    "endpoint": "461",
    "type": "number"
}
```

Responding to the callback with this number (response below) gives me a failure.

```
{
    "action": {
        "cli": "",
        "locale": "en-US",
        "maxDuration": 1000,
        "name": "ConnectPSTN",
        "number": "461",
        "suppressCallbacks": false
    },
    "instruction": []
}
```

The error I get is the following:

```
"reason":"GENERALERROR (NullReferenceException)"
```

Changing my response to include the original test number (460000000001) successfully connects the call. Why is this conversion happening, and am I supposed to automatically change numbers like "461" into their corresponding test number?

Cheers,
Morten

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like we have a bug on the test number, make sure you connect to 460000000001 for now and the team will look in to that. I assume you dont have the same problems when dialing real numbers.